# How to track URL in flutter with website platform

Tags: flutter

I want to do oAuth2 verification in my website login page and after that I want to get token from url with same page but issue is i can`t able to get URL.

below URL is OAuth2 url using this url I am doing authentication steps with website using flutter.

1st this website will open in browser after that login page will open and after login i will get access_token. But i facing difficulties how i can get access_code with html.window.location function.

I have tried with this code
WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) {

html.window.location.assign(
'https://example/connect/authorize?response_type=token&client_id=$clientId&redirect_uri=https://example.app/silentRenew&scope=getinfo');
});

Anyone have better solution than please give suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Pinal! I did an oAuth2 flux recently consuming Gitlab API. I suggest you to use
the oauth2 plugin: [oauth2](https://pub.dev/packages/oauth2). You just need to have the authorization endpoint, access token endpoint and the redirect url.
After this, you just need to call 3 methods.

1. Getting your AuthorizationCodeGrant.

   `var grant = oauth2.AuthorizationCodeGrant(identifier, authorizationEndpoint,  tokenEndpoint,secret: secret)`
2. Get Authorization Url.

`var authorizationUrl = grant.getAuthorizationUrl(redirectUrl);`

3. Get the returned Code.

`await grant.handleAuthorizationResponse(responseUrl.queryParameters);`

The method return your code automatically.

In my case, I used a webview instead opening the browser to listen the redirected url's. [WebView](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter)

You just have to pass the authorizationUrl as the initial page flag inside webview, and listen to the url's with `onPageStarted` flag. So what you wanna do is: when the redirectUrl ,which gives you the code to authorize your access token, is accessed you call the method 3, only in this moment. I hope this help you, let me know if you struggle with something.

Comment: Is it possible without secret key? becuase of in my case I don`t have secret key

Comment: I believe so. Since it's an optional parameter.